# Draw text on top layer of video embed when it's fullscreen

Tags: html, css, web

Now, I embed video from youtube and I have a trouble Which I can't draw anything (text, image, etc.) when video is fullscreen. So, what can I do to draw text or image (div) to show it when video fullscreen. I tried to use z-index, but it's not successful. 
 I want to make new controller for my video player don't user youtube controller, but video was embed from youtube. So, when user user fullscreen mod, I want to show a div which contains control like `play`, `pause`, etc.
 I already use `?wmode=transparent` but it's not work with fullscreen, It mean my controller not showed when I stay in fulscreen mode

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given much information, but this website details what you require, I think.

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/div-layers-float-over-flash-vimeo-youtube/

Comment: Hi, I already edited my question, hope you understand more about my problem, Thank you for your enthusiasm